# Show that a function of two variables is integrable

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $g : \mathbb{R}_{+}^* \times \mathbb{R}_{+}^* \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(x,t) = \frac{e^{-2t}-e^{-tx}}{t}$. Show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^*$, the function $f: t \mapsto g(x,t)$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}_{+}^*$.

There two ways for showing that $f$ integrable. We want to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^*} | f | < + \infty$. We could try using the Tonelli Theorem on $|f|$ by noticing that $f(t) = \int_2^x e^{-ty} dy$.
Thus we have that $\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^*} f =  \int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^*} ( \int_2^x e^{-ty} dy )dt $.

Noticing that $(t,y) \mapsto e^{-ty}$ is a measurable and positive function, we can use the Tonelli Theorem. We then get,

$\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^*} f= \int_2^x (\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^*} e^{-ty} dt) dy = \int_2^x \frac{1}{y} dy = \ln{x} - \ln{2}$ which is finite for all $x$?

Or we could try to majorate the function by a integrable function on $\mathbb{R}_{+}^*$ .

Is this right?

Comment: The latter seems way easier : with $t$ fixed, $g(t,x)$ is just a linear combination of two decaying exponential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second approach define $f(t)=|2-x|t$ if $t \leq 1$ and $2e^{-ct} $ if $t >1$ where $c =\min \{2,x\}$. Then $f$ majorizes $|g(x,t)|$ and $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Thank you! How did you find the majoration for $t \leq 1$ ? I can't see how to find this majoration.

Comment: For $t\leq 1$ I just use Mean Value Theorem for the exponential function. @vitalmath